# How grab current configuration from Windwos server and put it to the Ansible playbook?

Tags: windows, ansible

Need to grab current configuration from the Windows server and put it to the Ansible playbook.

How I can do it? Maybe some kind of tool? That grab Windows configuration?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What configuration are you trying to get and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: for example, IIS configuration, all applications configurations that stored on D drive (I mean all web.configs), some schedulers and already installed App on servers

Comment: Perhaps you'll get a better answer, but you may need to write your own powershell scripts for that. Or have a look at win_chocolately ansible packages, perhaps there is something there.

Comment: There are modules for each one of those, check `win_iis` modules in Ansible modules page. Application Configuration you can use the registry module to check for the application path and its settings

Comment: Thank you , I will use this modules !